# How to use gsutil with authenication key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, command-line-interface

I have a Apache Airflow DAG running on an on-prem server. In the DAG, I want to call Google Cloud CLI command `gsutil` to copy data file into GCP Storage bucket. In order to do that, I have to call `gcloud auth activate-service-account` first, then `gscutil cp`. Is it possible that I can merge two commands into just one? Or is it possible for me to setup the default authentication for my GCP service account, so I can skip the first command?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using shell commands to call GCP operations, firstly set a [GCP connection](https://www.revisitclass.com/gcp/how-to-configure-google-cloud-bigquery-connection-in-apache-airflow/) in Airflow, then you should consider to use Airflow GCP Operators such as [LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/google/modules/localfilesystemtogcsoperator), [GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/google/modules/gcstolocalfilesystemoperator) or Google API within **PythonOperator**.
Thus, you won't need to run extra command to authenticate. The **gcp_conn_id** that you prepared and specified
will already handle this step for you.

It is always better to use official providers' operators/sensors/hooks instead grueling bash commands. You can discover more [here](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/google).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will follow your advice to try other options to use GCP operators to move files to GCP storage bucket. My only concern is that if the file size is big, such as 30 GB, will GCP operator be able to handle it? Will I get a time out error?